# CMS style editor

Tags: content-management-system, editor, inline

I know drupal, and wordpress, but i am more please with hand coding site with php and javascript over html. You know EACH customer whant to have control, at least over text or correct mistake. so i am back to square one... go cms or not

I have evaluated something like : [UNIFY](http://unify.unitinteractive.com/index.php) a cheep inline editor, other do about the same thing... other use a database, this one not (i think)... so here is my question

When you what editability (it's a word ?) of text of .php webpage, but not need to build website with limited templating cms what are the option.... dont tell me to google.. tell me WHAT you used, what work, what effective. i looking for 1-2 option not 2000.

Asking first before getting to work is a good way of not loosing time... knowing what i know today about some mistake i have done in the past will save me time NOW.. that what i looking to do.

Comment: here is my shortlist : unify, pagelime, surreal, cushy... will have to sort and try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [Page Lime](http://www.pagelime.com/), which is a simple CMS where you (the developer) gets to set what parts are editable, and the client can view the page and edit only those content areas.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [SnappySnippets](http://www.snappysnippets.com), a free easy to use CMS. You basically assign a class to your editable regions and the cms does the magic. Your clients only get to edit the areas that you have tagged.